# Is there an academia-specific convention for possessive nouns?

Tags: publications, writing, grammar

I am fairly certain academic papers do not use apostrophe " ' " for contraction, like "won't", but what is the academic way (in engineering) to do this.  For example, " A humans walk cycle " , it is the walk cycle belonging to the human, so " A humans' walk cycle " seems appropriate.  However, I rarely see apostrophes used in academia, so should it be " The walk cycle of a human " instead?

I realize this is a bit of an english stack exchange, however, my question is the academic convention, not what is right or wrong in grammar.

Comment: In my experience, proper grammar (including the proper use of apostrophes) is always preferred. Perhaps you seen this mainly because engineers are not the best grammaticians?

Comment: The word you are looking for in the first sentence is not *conjunctions* but *contractions*.  Contractions are generally avoided in formal writing, but the apostrophe is also used for the *possessive* as in *human's*; this is perfectly acceptable.  There isn't an "academic convention" on this point as far as I know; these are just conventions for formal writing in general, and will be discussed in any English style guide.

Comment: *A humans' walk cycle* is incorrect as *humans'* would the possessive of the plural *humans* which is not what you want.  So anyway, this is better for English.SE or possibly ELL.SE (English.SE might close it as "general reference").

Comment: I agree with both of @NateEldredge's comments, but I've never been convinced that mathematics papers are so formal that I shouldn't use contractions.  I don't use contractions often, and I don't complain when referees or editors or copy editors want them removed, but I make no special effort to avoid them in the first place.

Comment: @NateEldredge , it is supposed to be the plural humans, as it refers to all humans, not a specific one.  If it was specific I would imagine something like person vs people.  Maybe human is a confusing example.  Thanks for pointing out the contraction thing

Comment: If "humans" is intentionally plural, then preceding it with "A" is misleading. Presumably, "A" was intended to  go with "cycle" rather than "humans", but then the whole phrase needs to be rewritten.

Comment: okay, I guess there are issues with the grammar im not aware of, but the question still remains, are there specific rules for academic grammar regarding apostrophe.  Is it just 'formal writing', since formal writing can use first person, but from the papers I read, it is usually third person

Comment: I disagree with the close votes, as the OP specifies that he is *not* looking for an answer on the English. Reopening.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think the asker is misinterpreting the sentence. "A human's walk cycle" makes perfect sense: it's the walk cycle of a generic human.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree that the OP is misinterpreting the sentence, unless it's one that he himself wrote (which wasn't obvious to me from the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with ff524 answer of there are *'no academia-specific convention to avoid the use of apostrophes to form possessive nouns.'*

However some universities now have developed guides in relation to grammar that can be referred to. It may also be worth while checking if your college has an academic writing centre(AWC) that runs workshops on writing skills. I know in my own university there is an AWC but also when at undergraduate a number of lecturers referred us to a general guide, *The Penguin Dictionary of English Grammar*.

For example on the [University of Canberra](http://www.canberra.edu.au/studyskills/writing/grammar) website they deal with a number of grammar points including the use of the apostrophe (see point 6). Here is a second [example](http://drhazelhall.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/2013_hall_rules-conventions_ac_writing.pdf) of a guide

Answer (score 15):

There is no academia-specific convention to avoid the use of apostrophes to form possessive nouns. Follow the usual rules of correct grammar and good style.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any style guide or convention that advises against using constructions that need apostrophes as a general rule, or says anything other than "Use correct English grammar and spelling to the best of your ability."

Style guides may advise against using contractions such as "won't" or "isn't" but that is because they are seen as being less formal, not because they need an apostrophe.

"A humans walk cycle" is nothing more than an error that wasn't picked up by the author or proofreader.

Comment: The OP is not proposing that he use "A humans walk cycle," but that instead of "A human's walk cycle" he use "walk cycle of a human" which is also technically correct.

Comment: @ff524 And I'm saying that I'm unaware of any style guide that recommends writing "the walk cycle of a human" just to avoid the apostrophe in "a human's walk cycle."